# Notion for partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am reading the book Mathematics for Machine Learning and I am quite confuse about the notion in the chapter Vector Calculus in this book. (This book is free to access here: https://mml-book.github.io/)

[image]

For example, in the definition 5.5, they denote the partial derivative of a function $f$ with respect to a variable $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$ as $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_i}}$ (italic $x$).

However, later in the book
[image]

They use the notion $\frac{\partial}{\partial{{\pmb{x}}}}$ (italic, bold $\pmb{x}$) for partial derivatives. When they denote $\pmb{x}$ (bold, italic) in this partial derivative, I think of the gradient (Jacobian), not the partial derivative, since $\pmb{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

May I ask if this is the correct way to denote partial derivative or I am missing some parts in the calculus.

Comment: Well, they do define $df/d\mathbf{x}$ in formula (5.40) in Def. 2.5, but it seems they are a bit inconsistent with $d$ vs. $\partial$...

Comment: Thank you, that's my point here. Because of the inconsistent between $d$ for total derivative with respect to entire vector $\pmb{x}$ and $\partial$ for some $x_i\in\pmb{x}$ (in section 5.2.1, it said for partial derivative, not the gradient, which make me quite confused)

Answer (score 1):

The *gradient* $\partial f/\partial\pmb{x}$ is the vector whose $i$th component is the *partial derivative* $\partial f/\partial x_i$.

Comment: Then why we just don't use the notion $\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}\pmb{x}}$ but the symbol $\partial$?

Comment: @flamingheart As I said, the vector's components are partial derivatives, not total ones. The notation's aim is $(\partial f/\partial\pmb{x})_i=\partial f/\partial x_i$.

Comment: I understand your point and got that $\partial{f}/\partial{\pmb{x}}$ is $\partial{f}/\partial{x_i}$, for $x_i\in\pmb{x}$. The problem I got here is that why they just don't write directly $\partial{f}/\partial{x_i}$ as they use in defintion 5.5 in the same book. I read some other books and authors always pointed out directly the partial derivative of some $x_i$, not $\pmb{x}$ as above.

Comment: @flamingheart But the two symbols denote different albeit related things. If you prefer, I'll define a vector as thus:$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\pmb{x}}:=\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\pmb{e}_i.$$So the authors aren't doing anything wrong or foolish here. You can work exclusively in index notation if you like, although that might make some linear algebra steps unnecessarily complicated later in the course.